# JQuery Serialize returning empty array

Tags: jquery, ajax, serialization

I've been stuck with this for hours, haven't been able to figure out any solution yet!!!
I've read the solutions for similar problems but none solves mine!
Any help would be much appreciated!!!
PS I've made sure that my select boxes have names, and are not disabled!!

```js
$('.filter-expense').change(function(){
    console.log('working');
    var dataval = $('#filter-form-expense').serialize();
    console.log(dataval);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#filter-form-expense').serialize(),
        url: 'get-filter-details-expense',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#filter_expense').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<form id="filter-form-expense">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <label>Project</label>
                <span class="form-control-feedback">
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </span>
                <select class="filter-expense form-control" name="AurigahrmExpenseExpenses2[project]">
                    <option disabled selected value> -- Select an Option -- </option>
                    <?php  foreach($dataProjects as $i=>$val1){
                        echo "<option value=".$i.">$val1</option>";
                    }?>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <label>Approver Name</label>
                <span class="form-control-feedback">
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </span>
                <select class="filter-expense form-control" name="AurigahrmExpenseExpenses2[approver]">
                    <?php foreach($dataApprovers as $i=>$val1){
                        echo "<option value=".$i.">$val1</option>";
                    }?> 
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <label>Superior Person</label>
                <span class="form-control-feedback">
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </span>
                <select class="filter-expense form-control" name="AurigahrmExpenseExpenses2[status]">
                    <option value="1">DC Comics</option>
                    <option value="2">MarvelsL</option>
                    <option value="3">Comp. Off</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <button type="button" name="button" class="button-type2 show-application" id="apply-leave">
                <i class="fa fa-plus pull-left"></i>
                <span class="button-text">
                    <i>Add Expense</i>
                </span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Include the `form` opening tag in your code sample

Answer (score 0):

Try using `serializeArray()` instead

```
var dataval = $('#filter-form-expense').serializeArray();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: dataval,
    url: 'get-filter-details-expense',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#filter_expense').html(data);
    }
});
```